# BC API with Custom Table

Tags: visual-studio-code, dynamics-business-central

I'm using Visual Studio Code to create custom API's to connect to Business Central tables.  Our implementation of BC includes a swath of custom tables.  My problem is that Visual Studio Code isn't seeing those table, or providing them as options in the AL Query Wizard.  What do I need to do in order to make these custom tables viewable via API?

Comment: Are you using separate apps, for example one for the business logic and one for the API?

Comment: Could you reproduce the behaviour in a minimal project and share it?